# How to store information about user-contributed changes?

Tags: database, database-design

I am writing an application where users can add information about books, publishers, sources (links to specific book) etc.
Each user should have ability to add or edit a book or information about any book (genre, publisher etc.).
When user adds or changes information about a book, this information will be available only for him while moderator doesn't check the correctness of the information. After verification the information will be available for all users.

You can see my database schema [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECpfS.jpg).

How should I store information about user-contributed changes?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a couple of basic approaches that you could use.

**Option 1: Keep pending changes in a parallel set of tables** - In this option you would more or less duplicate your schema with identical tables to your main schema, but with each table adding extra edit-related information, such as **proposed_by**, **proposed_datetime**, **approval_status**, **approved_by**, etc.

In this option you would track all proposed changes and they would be written into the main set of tables only when the moderator approved them.  You could either keep the history of proposed changes in these parallel tables or you could take approved and rejected changes out, leaving only pending changes.  That will depend on your business requirements.

**Option 2: Track pending changes in the main tables with a status flag** - In this option you would add the change tracking columns from Option 1 into your main tables, themselves.  You'd also have a **status_flag** column to indicate which records were official and which were pending proposed changes.  You could conceivably track rejected changes too, if you needed to.

**Which option to choose?**  All design is about trade-offs.  Depending on your needs you could use either of these options.  The issue with the first option is that you have to duplicate all of your tables and then add the change tracking columns on top of that.  The issue with the second option is that your code which *reads* the data would be more complicated because it would have to take into consideration filtering out all of the pending changes (and rejected changes, if you track them).

I'm a fan of clean code.  For that reason I would probably lean towards option 1, but then I don't know your business requirements, so you would have to make your own decision.